# Issue in my code while fetching product id,brand name and images using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am trying to fetch product details from the [sample product url](http://www.infantree.net/shop/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_113&product_id=1070) with below code-

```
def get_soup(url):
soup = None
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
except Exception as exc:
    print("Unable to fecth data due to..", str(exc))
finally:
    return soup

def get_product_details(url):
soup = get_soup(url)
sleep(1)
try:
    product_shop = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "buy"})
    if product_shop is not None:
        available_product_shop = soup.findAll('div')[2].find('span').text == "In Stock"
        if available_product_shop is not None:
            prod_details = dict()
            merchant_product_id = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'}).findAll('span')[3].text
            if merchant_product_id is not None:
                prod_details['merchant_product_id'] = merchant_product_id
                check_brand = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'description'}).findAll('span')[2].find('a')
                if check_brand is not None:
                    prod_details['brand'] = check_brand.text
                prod_details['merchant_image_urls'] = ",".join(list(filter(None, map(lambda x: x['href'].replace(",", "%2C"),
                                                                                     soup.find('div', attrs={
                                                                                         'class': 'left'}).findAll(
                                                                                         'a')))))
                check_price = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "price-old"})
                if check_price is not None:
                    prod_details['price'] = check_price.text.replace("SGD $", "")
                check_sale_price = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "price-new"})
                if check_sale_price is not None:
                    prod_details['sale_price'] = check_sale_price.text.replace("SGD $", "")
                return prod_details
except Exception as exc:
    print("Error..", str(exc))
```

Issue in above code is that I am not able to get the value of brand, product id and image urls are also not correctly fetched.

Can anyone please have a look of my code and help me to get correct details?

Comment: There is no element with `buy` class on the website you linked in the question :P Therefore, `product_shop` is None, if block is skipped and the `get_product_details` function returns None.

Comment: It's my bad, I have given the link of actual site but for fetching product detail need to use the product url. I have changed it , please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, my approach to answering your question was refactoring, simplifying and fixing the code. There is a lot of improvement in targeting the specific elements. It's cleaner and much more understandable. Feel free to ask me about the details that you don't understand. Good luck with your project (:

**Code:**

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_product_details(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    if soup.select_one('.stock').text != 'In Stock':
        return

    product_code_caption = soup.find('span', string=re.compile('Product Code:'))
    product_code = product_code_caption.next_sibling.strip()

    brand_container = soup.find('span', string=re.compile('Brand:'))
    brand = brand_container.find_next_sibling('a').string

    urls = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('.cloud-zoom-gallery')]

    old_price = soup.select_one('.price-old').text.replace('SGD $', '')
    new_price = soup.select_one('.price-new').text.replace('SGD $', '')

    prod_details = {
        'merchant_product_id': product_code,
        'brand': brand,
        'merchant_image_urls': urls,
        'price': old_price,
        'sale_price': new_price
    }

    return prod_details


import pprint
pprint.pprint(get_product_details('http://www.infantree.net/shop/index.php?route=product/product&path=59_113&product_id=1070'))
```

**Output:**

```
{'brand': 'Britax',
 'merchant_image_urls': ['http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Britax-Light-Travel-System_BlackThunder-683x1024-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Formula-One-Flame-Red1024x1024-510x510-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Formula-One-Cosmos-Black1024x1024-768x768-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Black-Thunder-Ocean-Blue1024x1024-768x768-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Black-Thunder-Flame-Red1024x1024-768x768-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Black-Thunder-Cosmos-Black1024x1024-768x768-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Formaula-One-Ocean-Blue1024x1024-510x510-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Olympian-Blue-Cosmos-Black1024x1024-510x510-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Olympian-Blue-Flame-Red1024x1024-768x768-500x500.jpg',
                         'http://www.infantree.net/shop/image/cache/data/Britax '
                         'Products/Olympian-Blue-Ocean-Blue1024x1024-100x100-500x500.jpg'],
 'merchant_product_id': 'BRITAX Light + i-Size Travel System',
 'price': '1,032.00',
 'sale_price': '699.00'}
```

Comment: Thanks Jatimir for reviewing my code and sharing the powerful re use.One issue I am facing in image fetching. If you change the url of the product with some other -http://www.infantree.net/shop/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=327; your logic does'not work so can you check once?